# Java - Get/set methods receiving and returning "null"

Tags: java, null, get, set

I'm a beginner in Java.  I'm trying, for training purpose, to build myself a chess game application.  Within my class Case, that will be used to instanciate all the 64 cases of my board, I write get/set methods to find if there's a Piece occupant in the instances of the case.

I read that returning "null" is a bad practice, so I throw an exception instead to signify that the case is free.  But, I wonder how to set the occupant's pointer to "null"; can I simply push "null" as a parameter when I will call this method?

Also, could taking/returning "null" be an acceptable/good practice?

```
public Piece getOccupant(){
    if (this.occupant == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(this.occupant + " is Empty");
    return this.occupant;
}
public void setOccupant(Piece newOccupant){
    this.occupant = newOccupant;
}
```

Thanks!

[Update]

Thanks to all of your for your comments, ideas, corrections and recommendations.  Here is the updated version of my code for this part, and I feel satisfied with it, as it served its purpose (increase my understanding thru practice).

```
/*
 * Modifiers of Occupant
 */
/**
 * Used to find if a Piece is located in this Cell
 * @return a Piece reference to the occupant.  Will send a 
 * null pointer if cell is empty
 */
public Piece getOccupant(){
    return this.occupant;
}
/**
 * Used to set a new occupant in the Cell.
 * @param newOccupant is a reference to a Piece instance, 
 * and should be set to null if the cell is emptied, or using
 * the method clear().
 */
public void setOccupant(Piece newOccupant){
    this.occupant = newOccupant;
}
/**
 * Used to verify if a Cell is empty of any occupant
 * @return true if cell is empty.
 */
public boolean isEmpty(){
    if(this.occupant == null)
        return true;
    return false;
}
/**
 * Free the cell of any occupant, if any were
 */
public void clear(){
    this.occupant = null;
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I don't see why it would be bad to return null in this situation if the cell has no occupants. 1+ for your desire to write better code!

Comment: Perhaps its just me, but throwing an IllegalArgumentException in a method that doesn't have any arguments is not appropriate.

Comment: Please do not have an API that can return null.  This means you will need to check every time you use it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A space on the board being unoccupied is not exceptional.  Its normal and will always be true for the majority of the board.  You should not be throwing exceptions here; exceptions should only be thrown for an unexpected event that signify a significant problem with what you are trying to do.

You can certainly pass null to a setter (except for a primitive type like int/long).

It might be better to add some convenience methods, an isEmpty method to your Space class:

```
public boolean isEmpty(){
   if (this.occupant == null) 
      return true;
   return false;
}
```

and also perhaps a clear method

```
public void clear() {
    this.occupant = null;
}
```

that way you don't have to test on the nullity of the getter result, and you don't need to pass null to set -- this has the added benefits of being easily testable, and creates a API that is meaningful to your Space class.

Comment: In addition, should your implementation change, you only need to change the null check in one location rather than refactor every single calling method.

Comment: You can simplify the isEmpty() function:
public boolean isEmpty() {
  return this.occupant == null;
}

Answer (score 6):

If you want to forbid null values, you should do it on the setter method:

```
public void setOccupant(Piece occupant) {
  if (occupant == null) throw new NullPointerException("occupant");
  this.occupant = occupant;
}
```

Note that some people prefer to throw IllegalArgumentException. Either way, the point is to "fail fast" as soon as someone sets a forbidden value.

Having said all of that, a chess board certainly can have empty positions, so allowing null seems to make more sense.

I suggest you read "Effective Java, 2nd Edition" by Josh Bloch.

Answer (score 3):

Where did you read that recommendation? In my opinion, there is absolutely nothing wrong about returning `null`, provided that `null` conveys some useful information and does not indicate a severe error condition. In this case, it is perfectly normal for a chess cell to not contain a piece, and I would definitely expect `getOccupant()` to return null in that case.

Answer (score 1):

If the caller is aware of NULL return values, it's not bad to return NULL values by callee.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning null or throwing an exception, you should create a class "Empty", "None", "Void", something like that, that you would assign to all your Case that are empty.

Answer (score 0):

small suggestion 
no need of if block, you can simplify your code by simply returning the output of expression

```
public boolean isEmpty(){
    return this.occupant == null
}
```